# Alternative to complex replace() function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have been asked to do a bit of work on a SQL Server 2005 query that has 26 (!) nested `Replace` function calls.

There are two issues with this query.

The first is that the 26 replace functions are not enough, a few more are needed, but the query is hitting some size limitations (it's a stored procedure and its making using of `sp_MSforEachDB`).

The second problem is that the query is just not legible at this stage.

I would like to use table variable with a lookup, but the issue is that the replace query is being used to replace values in one column with values from another column. It does however all work, apparent from not replacing enough strings.

Here is a simplified example to hopefully better explain what I am trying to do.

Table to be converted

```
ID   MainText                         Ptext1    Ptext2     Ptext3
1    Have a %Ptxt1 %Ptxt2             Apple     Tonight    
2    %Ptxt1 likes %Ptxt2 at %Ptxt3    Sally     Cake       Midnight
```

The desired result for 1 is "Have a Apple Tonight", the desired result for 2 is "Sally Likes Cake at Midnight".

The current SQL Looks a bit like

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'IF ''?'' LIKE ''%Database%''
Select Replace(Replace(Replace([Maintext], '%Ptxt1' , [Ptext1]),'%Ptxt2',[Ptext2]),'Ptxt3', [Ptext3]) from dbo.mytable
```

Please forgive any mistakes in the example.

I have seen nice examples of people using Table variables to store parameters for the replace function - but I haven't seen any where a column reference is used instead of a static string, is this possible ?

Comment: If the data in your tables is broken, fix it and then stop inserting broken data. Don't do these kinds of heavy calculations during select.

Comment: Sadly not a possibility, the data is created in this way by an application. Questionable I know, but it has to be rectified in the Select statement.

Comment: You could create ON INSERT triggers that do that.

Comment: The only way I can think of not to have nested REPLACE functions to do this is to use a LOOP instead.   I don't see how a table variable will help here.

Comment: Create a CLR function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Call your base table: MyData.
Create a new table named MyValues (id, Token, data_value). the ID is FK to you base table. for each record in MyData, insert the values of field names into MyValues. 
So, MyValues looks like

```
Id        Token        data_value
====      ======       ==========
1         Ptxt1        Apple
1         Ptxt2        Tonight
2         Ptxt1        Sally
2         Ptxt2        Cake
2         Ptxt3        Midnight
```

and so on...

Then you can join MyTable with MyValues.

Now, one way of solving the problem, is looping on MyData and inner loop on MyValues.

```
declare @i int
for each value in MyData
begin
  @i++
  read MyDaya.MainText into @mainText
  for each value in MyValues where ID = Id of the MainData
  begin
    read MyValues.data_value into @actualValue
    read MyValues.Token into @token
    @mainText = Replace(@mainText, @toekn, @actualValue)
    Update MyData with mainText or do what ever appropriate   
  end
end
```

This is pseudo-code, I hope you can implement that in T- SQL

Comment: With that MyValues table, there is no way to know what data_value replaces what token.

Comment: The only (viable) way to implement something like this in T-SQL would be to create a CLR function...